# USB-Webcam on Android 4.4+

Tags: android, usb, webcam

I am into a new project which requires me to use a USBconnected "Webcam".
The whole fun should run on Android 4.4.

my little story was:

- I try multiple apps which do this - all work on both my testing devices
- adapting some NDK lib that directly uses /dev/video0. This didnt work due to read-permission that was not granted in a new File("dev/video0").canRead() check. Although my unix permissions are correct, this seems to not work due to some new check on Android 4.4. (the whole thing was suggested here: [Connect Android phone to a USB Web camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392007/connect-android-phone-to-a-usb-web-camera) )
- next: discover the UsbAccessory API that supposedly easens a lot of the above.

  - ´find no documentation or anything about how to correctly handle a webcam
  - I still try, but don't come further than finding no device via

  usbManager.getAccessory();

I've also tried to discover devices by filtering for a USB_ATTACHED broadcast but nothing triggers.

So I am starting to ask myself how the hell do others find the devices & communicate with them to get the pictures?

Anyone has sources from which i could learn, or a tutorial or something?

Little update from my side:
- I've gotten access by using the Android USB Host API e.g. UsbDevice instead of UsbAccessory. 
- I have the connection and everything setup fine, and can now send binary data to my webcam and supposedly receive.

I can now send controlCommands via connection.controlTransfer(...) or use a "UsbRequest" in order to receive data.

However, I couldn't find any documentation to "make the camera submit pictures" to me. My Endpoint is of type XFER_INT (=interrupts).

I am continuing to try sending out various commands (e.g. binary values) but haven't had any success so far.

Comment: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. `

Comment: Have you tried the standard camera APIs, like `MediaRecorder`?

Comment: Hey, no I've not. But I a wasn't aware of the fact, that MediaRecorder has the ability to use an external USB-Webcam.

Comment: I've updated the current status of my little project